# activator.createinstance(type, boolean)

Tags: c#

In C#, Without creating object for a class, how to call or invoke a function in it just by using **activator.createinstance(type, boolean)**? In Type I have got the namespace name and class name

Comment: 1) Why?  2) Is this an instance method or a static method?  Also, you do realize that `Activator.CreateInstance()` creates an instance of the class, right?

Comment: Are you asking how to invoke a `static` method via reflection?

Comment: You shopuld first retrieve the actual `Type`from its name by using `Type.GetType(<yourAssemblyQualifiedClassName>)`

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type, bool)
```

Is actually creating an object of your class. However you shoulnd't pass an string but the actual type.

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass))
```

Unless the method you want to call is static you need to create an instance of your class to call it. If it is static the following should work:

```
MyClass.MyMethod()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourClass))
```